# How do you make a range in bash case sensitive?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use a for loop like this, where the range consists of letters, both uppercase and lowercase. The problem is, bash doesn't differentiate uppercase and lowercase when it's within a range. How do I make it case sensitive? TIA.

```
for s in {a..z,A..Z}
do
    echo ${s}
done
```

Comment: You could use `{A..z}`, but the problem is you would have `[  ] ^ _ \`` in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the letters in that order, just use:

```
for s in {a..z} {A..Z}
```

There's no requirement that `bash` only allows a single brace expansion per line.

The two forms currently allowed are mutually exclusive, being either a selection (of two or more) or a range:

```
{<val1>,<val2>[,...]}
{<from>..<to>[..<incr>]}
```

The brace expression `{a..z,A..Z}` simply expands, using the *first* form, to the two words (not ranges):

```
a..z
A..Z
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got the syntax wrong.

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.25(1)-release
$ echo {a..k} {A..K}
a b c d e f g h i j k A B C D E F G H I J K
$ echo {a..k,A..K}
a..k A..K
```